# Read table from local sql-server from an ubuntu virtual machine (virtualbox)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am on a machine with Windows 10 as the host OS and I have an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine that was installed using virtualbox. I also have SQL server running on Windows and spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7 installed on my virtual machine (Ubuntu).

On my windows machine, I can read tables from the server using pandas using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.io.sql
import pyodbc

# Parameters
server = 'localhost'
db = 'Claro'

# Create the connection
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')

# query db
sql = """

SELECT *
  FROM [Claro].[dbo].[TMP_FRD_CTV_TOTAL]

"""
# Excute Query here
df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, chunksize=10000)
```

I want to know if it is possible to read the same table from my SQL Server using pyspark from the virtual machine. If it is possible, what do I have to do?

Thanks a lot!

Rodrigo.

Comment: Try to put your virtualmachie in bridge mode and access it by public Ip address provided. You may have to add some firewall rules and grant some permissions to access your database server remotelly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it won't be from localhost like is in your code, you need to change to its public ip address ( you can get it on google just search find my ip or anything like that), like if you were connecting to a remote db service.

Although the VM runs in the same computers, the resources are totally isolated

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can access the host SO on 10.0.2.2. I was even able to read a table from the SQL server on the host into a pandas dataframe. I have no idea how to do that in Spark.

Comment: the localhost ip is 127.0.0.1, 10.0.2.2 is probably your local network ip, if it doesn't using the public ip maybe not even be the best idea, because you will be uploading and downloading the data though your ISP consuming the double of the bandwith, considering your up speed = down speed, and charged~counted the same, the port used on spark is different, than the port on sqlserver, you should check if they are allowed https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html, you could use some simple webserver to check if you connect with this ports

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I made it. The code I used was the following:

```
# Import libraries
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/rodrigo/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7')
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Basics").getOrCreate()

# Read data
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433")\
        .option("dbtable", "[Claro].[dbo].[TMP_FRD_CTV_TOTAL]")\
        .option("user", "spark").option("password", "1234").load()
```

Thanks for the help guys!